# How to install nvcc on macOS catalina 10.15.7 without GPU?

Tags: macos, cuda, nvidia, nvcc, cudnn

When run:

`which nvcc`

It says:

`nvcc not found`

And I did not found clear guide to install nvcc,on macOS catalina 10.15.7.

Because I am trying to run https://github.com/jugg1024/Text-Detection-with-FRCN.git. But on cammand:

`make -j16 && make pycaffe`:

From here:

[image]

It gives this error:
[image]

Thats why i do need `nvcc` installation.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Recent versions of CUDA/nvcc (CUDA 11 and beyond) are no longer supported for use on macOS.  See [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-10-and-macos-10-14/65672) and [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-cuda-toolkit-developer-tools-mac-hosts) Furthermore, without a CUDA capable GPU, it's not obvious why you would want or need `nvcc`.  Very likely you are confused about something here/doing something wrong here.

Comment: @Robert Crovella, Thanks for your reply. I edited my question, this is why i need ```nvcc```. I am facing this error and its probably due to not having ```nvcc```.

Comment: @Robert Crovella, yea I am confused about, whether we can work with ```nvcc```, ```cuda```, and ```cuDNN```  without having GPU or not on mac? I googled but its already confusing, some says we can some says we cannot.

Comment: no, you cannot use or work with cuda and cuDNN without having a CUDA GPU.  Yes, you can build codes but *you cannot run them without a GPU*.  So you need to find out how to build caffe and pycaffe so that they don't require a GPU (Or else switch to a machine/system that has a GPU).  When you locate those instructions, they won't depend on `nvcc`.  So what you are trying to do here is not useful on the mac.

Comment: @Robert Crovella! You can post these comments as answer, so that i accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since CUDA 11.0, macOS is not a supported environment for CUDA.

The last supported environment was based on CUDA 10.2 (see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.2/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#system-requirements)) and a macOS version of 10.13.x

There has never been a supported `nvcc` install, CUDA install, or CUDA version for macOS 10.15.x

If you don't have a CUDA-capable GPU in your mac, it's not clear why you would want to install `nvcc` or CUDA. They could possibly be used to build code, but that code wouldn't be runnable on that machine.

If you do have a CUDA capable GPU in your mac, you would want to follow the above linked instructions carefully, noting carefully the machine requirements, such as supported macOS version.  CUDA 10.2 would be the latest/last version of CUDA you could install on that mac.

Comment: "If you don't have a CUDA-capable GPU in your mac, it's not clear why you would want to install nvcc or CUDA."

One reason might be wanting to cross-compile CUDA kernels.

Comment: cross-compilation isn't supported by NVIDIA in a mac platform/environment.  I think you just meant "compilation".  Yes, you could use a non-GPU-equipped mac (with an appropriate toolchain) to build mac CUDA binaries.  You could also use it to run tools that were relevant in that era, for example the visual profiler.  I didn't say "it's unimaginable" I said "its not clear".  For beginners, its important for them to quickly discover that CUDA isn't usable (for execution purposes) without a GPU, and if you study some of the previous comments above, you'll see possibly evidence of that.

Comment: I precisely meant cross-compilation; e.g., one might want to compile CUDA kernels on an M1 MacBook for x86 on Linux. Whether that's easy or even possible is another question. While it's important to lead beginners down the right path, it's advisable to stay correct along the way.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "correct".  All I said was "its' not clear".  And I already mentioned *in the answer* that one reason might be to "build code".

Comment: One reason to develop and compile using nvcc for a Mac is that people are used to Mac keyboards and tools. Once you go Linux/different machine development gets slower. This is at least why I want nvcc for macos.